# Forget some of the [memory]-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

There are quite a few tags related to memory.  Can we synonymize/burninate some of them?

Here are the ones I found so far:

- [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory): 488 followers, 18.1k questions

  > Use this tag for memory management or issues in programming. For questions about memory hardware issues or errors in general software, go to http://superuser.com, or http://serverfault.com if this is related to enterprise-level hardware or software.
- [ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ram): 7 followers, 905 questions

  > RAM (Random Access Memory) is a form of computer data storage. A random access device allows stored data to be accessed in very nearly the same amount of time for any storage location, so data can be accessed quickly in any random order.
- [android-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-memory) 5 followers, 189 questions

  > android-memory is generally Runtime Memory of Android device. This is the memory which is required run time for the execution of application or process or service. Typically RAM plays this role.

I think we should burninate [android-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-memory) because it really isn't any different than memory on any other computer (Android is Linux-based IIRC), and synonymize [ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ram) to [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory).

Comment: The problem with these puns in titles is that you tend to immediately vote up without even reading the question :-)

Answer (score 4):

Although it's probably true that "Android memory isn't any different than memory on any other computer", the [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory) tag description says it's about memory **management**. Is Android memory management the same as memory management on any other computer? I don't think so; there are [issues specific](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) to how Android manages memory.

However, issues specific to Android memory could be simply tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory), as [suggested by @assylias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295987/forget-some-of-the-memory-related-tags/296031?noredirect=1#comment202453_296031).

I do agree that [ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ram) should be synonymized with [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory).

Comment: [android-memory] could be replaced by [android][memory]

Comment: @assylias Hm. Good point. I'll include that in my answer

Comment: It would be easy for someone to be an expert in andriod-memory therefore it is a good tag.